# Is it true that almost everywhere convergence implies that the supremum of the difference goes to zero outside a set of small measure?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I've been studying modes of convergence recently and came upon the following problem. A sequence of functions $f_n$ is given in a finite measure space $(E,m)$ and it's said that they converge $a.e.$ to a function $f$ with finite values. I've to show that for any $\delta>0$ I can find a set $F$ with $m(E$\ $F)<\delta$ such that $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}sup_{x\in F}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$.

The first thing I noted that here there were additional conditions/assumptions and it's not the same as deriving $L^{\infty}$ convergence from $a.e.$ convergence, which is not true as far as I know. But here the task is to show that $a.e.$ convergence implies convergence of the supremums of the difference outside a small set. I don't see how to construct this set $F$. How do I solve such a problem? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Isn't this Egorov's Theorem?

Comment: you may see littlewood's three principles for related discussion

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Egorov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov's_theorem).